# Cross-File Yank and Put in Vim in MacOS 10.12.3

Tags: vim

I am having some trouble with cross-file yanking and putting in vim. I have clipboard set to unnamed to have a system-wide clipboard. Even if I use "+y and "+p without the universal clipboard the yanking does not put in the other file. Is there something I should do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set clipboard=unnamed` (or the more portable `set clipboard^=unnamed`) is not sufficient for "cross-file yanking". The necessary requirement is that your Vim is built with clipboard support. You can verify it with:

```
echo has('clipboard')
```

`1` means that you have clipboard support and that you can use `"+` or the `unnamed` option.

`0` means that none of that will work unless you install a *proper* Vim, MacVim on Mac OS X.